# Merge 2 arrays without overwrite

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want merge 2 arrays with the same fields by gkey but I don't want to override the first array  felids I'm using map() and find() but it overwrites the first array and undefined row

here is my code

```js
let x = [{id:1 , name: "hi", gkey: 6,np:1000, op:0}
  ,{id:2 , name: "hello", gkey: 7,np:5000, op:0}
  ,{id:3 , name: "h", gkey: 8,np:3000, op:0}];

let y = [{id:11,name: "hi" ,gkey:6,np:0,op:100},{id:22,name:"hi",gkey:8,np:0,op:800},];

var marr = x.map(i => y.find(s => s.gkey === i.gkey))

console.log(marr);
```

here is my result:
[image]

i want my merge data result like this:

```
{id:1 , name: "hi", gkey: 6,np:1000, op:100}

{id:2 , name: "hello", gkey: 7,np:5000, op:0}

{id:3 , name: "h", gkey: 8,np:3000, op:800}
```

any solutions?

Comment: Your question is unrelated to TypeScript. This is pure JavaScript without any TypeScript feature.

Comment: @jabaa this is test code explain what I want I'm going use it in the angular project so I don't want to have conflict in typescript, that's why I say type script sorry for bad Title

Comment: How do you want to merge the elements? By position, by `name`, by `gkey`?

Comment: Do you want to add `np` and `op` ?

Comment: I see this more as a filter not a merge operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solutions are just fine, but I was wondering what if the operation is truly a merge one, and the y array contain more items than x.

```js
let x = [
  { id: 1, name: "hi", gkey: 6, np: 1000, op: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: "hello", gkey: 7, np: 5000, op: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: "h", gkey: 8, np: 3000, op: 0 },
];

let y = [
  { id: 11, name: "hi", gkey: 6, np: 0, op: 100 },
  { id: 22, name: "hi", gkey: 8, np: 0, op: 800 },
  { id: 33, name: "new entry in Y arr", gkey: 8, np: 0, op: 5545 },
];

let result = x.concat(y)
              .reduce((acc, current) => 
              {
                let found = acc.find((i) => i["gkey"] === current["gkey"]);
                if (found) {
                  found.op = current["op"];
                  return acc;
                }
                acc.push(current);
                return acc;
              }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can i use acc.find with 2 filter?

Comment: not sure, I get your question right, but in this case, find is better than the filter, it will return the first found item faster compare to other.

Comment: and how can set (y) np to (x) op

Comment: just reverse the order of concatenation, first one will be overridden by the second. in this case, y.concat(x).reduce.... do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there, but have to create and return a merged object:

```js
let x = [{id:1 , name: "hi", gkey: 6,np:1000, op:0}
  ,{id:2 , name: "hello", gkey: 7,np:5000, op:0}
  ,{id:3 , name: "h", gkey: 8,np:3000, op:0}];

let y = [{id:11,name: "hi" ,gkey:6,np:0,op:100},{id:22,name:"hi",gkey:8,np:0,op:800},];

var marr = x.map(elX => {
  const elY = y.find(s => s.gkey === elX.gkey);
  return { ...elX, np: elX.np + (elY?.np ?? 0), op: elX.op + (elY?.op ?? 0) };
  });

console.log(marr);
```

Answer (score 0):

insert the elements of y into x individually  , like code below :

```js
let x = [{id:1 , name: "hi", gkey: 6,np:1000, op:0}
  ,{id:2 , name: "hello", gkey: 7,np:5000, op:0}
  ,{id:3 , name: "h", gkey: 8,np:3000, op:0}];

let y = [{id:11,name: "hi" ,gkey:6,np:0,op:100},{id:22,name:"hi",gkey:8,np:0,op:800},];

y.forEach(element => {
    x.push(element)

});

console.log(x);
```